# Determining the preposition before 'which' to replace 'when/where'

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

When using when/where in adjective clauses, we're allowed to substitute it with this form:

**when = preposition + which**

Or

**where = preposition + which**

First of all, I want to show an example:

> Monday is the day when they will come then (**on** that day).

I'm sure it can be rewritten as follows:

> Monday is the day **on** which they will come then.

That example above is what I took from my book and I'm able to understand because there's a hint in the bracket.

Another example I took from a novel: Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows

> He was still at the narrow fragment **in**  which, for a split second,
> he had thought  he saw Dumbledore’s eye.

I want to know where *in* comes from. At that moment, he's (Harry) holding a broken mirror on his hand, by the way, according to the story. And which conjunction is that? 'Where' or 'when'? My point question is just how to know which preposition we would use, for instance, when we want to subsitute **where** with **preposotion + which**.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what book you took the first example from, but *then* is incorrect in both cases.

We speak of seeing a reflection *in* a mirror, so the mirror is the place *where* we see it. It has nothing to do with time (when).